# Regex - only allow single spaces within a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to restrict a string to only allow letters, numbers, hyphens, ampersands, apostrophes and single spaces.

From a bit of searching I've got this so far:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9-'&\s]{1,}$
```

But this allows for double spaces.  How do I write the regular expression so that it only allows single spaces (there might not be any at all)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match any of the *other* allowed values, followed by an optional single space:

```
^\s?([A-Za-z0-9-'&]\s?){1,}$
```

(I also added an optional one at the start, if that's allowed)

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
^([A-Za-z0-9-'&]+\s?)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with different scenario it works fine with me
^\b(?!.*?\s{2})[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,50}\b$

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\b(?!.*?\s{2})[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,50}\b$", ErrorMessage ="String is not valid"]
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```